# How to make switch statement with optionals?

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, option-type

I'm working with text fields and json data. I want to test if the json data is != nil, if it is, then I fill it's field with that info, if it's == nil then I put a placeholder in its field instead. Like this:

```
   if memberInfo?.createDate != nil {

    self.activeSinceTextField.text = stringToDateToString((memberInfo?.createDate)!)

  } else {
    placeHolder("Enter Here".localized())
    self.activeSinceTextField.attributedPlaceholder = placeHolderText
  }

  if memberInfo?.birthDate != nil

  {self.birthdayTextField.text = stringToDateToString((memberInfo?.birthDate)!)

  } else

  {     placeHolder("Enter Here".localized())
    self.birthdayTextField.attributedPlaceholder = placeHolderText
  }
```

I have a lot of fields and I'm thinking a switch statement would make this a lot cleaner. I'm just not sure how to make one for this type of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Version 1

This is how you define the 4 outcomes with a `switch`

```
switch (memberInfo?.createDate, memberInfo?.birthDate) {
case (.Some, .Some): break
case (.Some, nil): break
case (nil, .Some): break
case (nil, nil): break
}
```

Now just replace the `break(s)` with the code you want to execute for each scenario.

### Version 2

Here you have `createDate` and/or `birthDate` unwrapped when available

```
switch (memberInfo?.createDate, memberInfo?.birthDate) {
case (let .Some(createDate), let .Some(birthDate)):
    print(createDate, birthDate)
case (let .Some(createDate), .None):
    print(createDate)
case (.None, let .Some(birthDate)):
    print(birthDate)
case (.None, .None):
    print("Both are nils")
}
```

### Legend

- `.Some`: means here there is something
- `.None`: means this is nil
- `_`: means is a jolly, it means I don't care what there is here

Comment: Thanks for this, I have a stupid question but why use .Some?

Comment: @SwiftyJD: I use `.Some` when I need to say: here there is __something__.

Comment: I see, I have 8 categories to go through, is this the most efficient way to approach it but substituting nil for each category?

Comment: @SwiftyJD: In this case just follow the Version 3.

Comment: @vacawama: thank you for pointing it out. I updated my answer!